# Would I consume less electricity by choosing to run my software with PyPy3 over Cpython3?

Tags: julia, cpu-usage, jit, cpython, pypy

Would I consume less by running my scripts with [PyPy3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy) instead of Cpython provided that my laptop is turned on 24/7 regardless of the choice of Python's implementation?

And more general, would choosing a [JIT-compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) language, as [Julia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_(programming_language)), to perform a set of tasks provide me with such advantage over choosing an interpreted language, like Python (implemented as Cpython)?
Are there any other advantages than latency that [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) has when compared with interpreted implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of electricity consumed by a CPU depends on the computational load.
Hence the answer to this question simply depends on how much computing power you use.
The [benchmarks](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/) clearly show that generally code is fastest in Julia and hence here the amount of consumed energy will be lowest.